# Normal map seems fine, but shades completely wrong (2.8 Beta)

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, normal-map

I'm trying to bake a normal map from my high poly sculpted model to my low poly model.

From left to right:
 1. Lowpoly model without the normal map
 2. Lowpoly model with the normal map
 3. Highpoly model.

I use Non-Color image input, the texture itself looks fine, but the LookDev preview is completely broken. What is going on?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You need to plug a normal mode between the texture and the normal socket of the principled shader

Comment: You are right. I've tested this and added an answer based on it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is missing is a **Normal Map** node between the Image Texture node and the Principled Shader node:

[image]